# Animation hasStarted() or hasEnded() is not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-animation

I'm a beginner with the development of applications for Android and I just got a problem that I cannot solve.

I have a Rotation animation that loads from a layout and it works great, smooth and fast, but when I call an if statement with `hasStarted()` or `hasEnded()` nothing happens.

Here's the code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==boton){
    int r;
    Random n = new Random();
    r=n.nextInt(ncategorias);
    Animation rotacion = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.rotar);
    boton.startAnimation(rotacion);
    if(rotacion.hasEnded()) {
      categoria.setText(categorias[r]);
    }
    lista.PrimerNodo = lista.PrimerNodo.siguiente;
    hola=lista.PrimerNodo.datos.toString();
    vistajuego.setText(hola);
    }
}
```

Any help would be very useful!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're starting the animation and immediately checking if the animation has ended which is doubtful unless it simply doesn't do anything.  What you want to do is implement an [AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) callback and set it to that animation, assuming you want to set that text immediately when the animation finishes.